# Ring Homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{20} \to \mathbb Z_{30}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

We need to find all ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{20} \to \mathbb Z_{30} $ ;
I read its solution somewhere which states that : 
$R : \mathbb Z_{20} \to \mathbb Z_{30}$ defined by $R(x) = ax$ , $a$ belongs to $\mathbb Z_{30}$ is a ring homomorphism if :

$1) \  a^2 = a$ and ,

$2) |a| \ \Big| \ 20 , \ \ \  |a| \ \Big| \ 30$

$1)$ is acceptable , but i couldn't understand $2)$.. why order of $a$ should divide both $20$ and $30$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of $a$ obviously divides $30$. It must also divide $20$, because
$$
20a=R(20)=R(0)=0
$$

Answer (score 2):

I will state here one theorem and one property of group Homomorphism which will allow you to see why (2) hold true.

$\textbf{Lagrange's Theorem}$

If $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $|H|$ divides $|G|$.

Proof: It's proof is based on cosets of $H$ in $G$ and can be found in any standard textbook.

$\textbf{Property of Group Homomorphism}$

If $|g|$ is finite, then $|\phi(g)|$ divides $|g|$.($\phi$ is some homomorphism)

Proof: $g^n=e_{G}  \Rightarrow (\phi(g))^{n}=e_{\bar{G}} \Rightarrow |\phi(g)|$  divides $|g|$.

Now, back to the problem, since $\phi(1)=a$ and Ring form an abelian group under addition. So, form a cyclic subgroup of $<a>$ whose order must divide order of $Z_{30}$ and $|e_{z_{20}}|=20$ in $Z_{20}$.

Hence, $ |a| \ \Big| \ 20 , \ \ \  |a| \ \Big| \ 30$